# How long should I leave a question without an accepted answer, even if suitably answered?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

Although this seems like a simple question, there are some things worth considering.

If I ask a question and it has been suitably answered, I usually mark it accepted.

However due to the mechanics of Stack Overflow, leaving a question without an accepted answer can sometimes catch a wider array of suitable answers (e.g. due to the potential reward factor for respondents), which may be more helpful to casual readers.

My question is: should I be accepting the first suitable answer, or should I allow more time, e.g. a day or two, to try and catch an "initial" wide range of answers?

Comment: If something isn't off topic, too broad, unclear, or primary opinion... why are you closing your own question?  If it *is* one of those, why did you ask it in the first place?

Comment: close, as in mark correct.. Well hopefully i asked a suitable question anyway, i just notice that initially questions get more answers when an answer hasn't been marked as the correct answere

Comment: You are mixing up closing and accepting. You might accept an answer when ever you like. A question does not get closed by accepting and you might change your acceptance at any time. Closing would be making a questions invisible in the front page for lower rep users due to problems with the question, which might or might not be solved. Since SO is not intended to answer questions for the person asking the question but for a bigger audience like a living library the term close does not fit for accepting.

Comment: @Saruman _"... and catch an "initial" wide range of opinions?"_ Well,, opinion based questions are OT. Leaving your question unaccepted, might intrigue other's to have a closer look at it, and may be mark it as _opiniion based_ :P ...

Comment: I guess its given that the hypothetical question is not too broad that it would fall under that category, however since there is more than 1 way to skin a cat (in technology) some answers (for instance) might target speed, readability, elegance, ect. and leaving it unaccepted might allow an initial wider solution set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, I agree with you. And let me just explain to clarify what do I mean by that.

---

I think you should accept an answer when you think that:

1. It is *sufficiently good* - correctly *identifying and addressing* your need, and
2. It is a *working* solution for you - *not* flawed - at *some point of time*.

There is **no need to bother the community** by leaving your questions well-answered but not having an *accepted* answer when you already think that an answer among them is **good enough** (or, using your term, **suitable**) for you. *Accept* the answer, and **don't wait for the best**.

> It doesn't mean that you should accept *any* working solution or *the
>   first* working solution. No. It also doesn't mean that you cannot wait
>   longer. No. It only means that, after you carefully judge, when one of
>   the answers is **good enough** to be accepted, then you should accept
>   it.
>
> Thus, the *time factor* (how long you got to wait) is **irrelevant**. It
>   is the *quality* of the answer that matters. If there is *no*
>   sufficiently good answer till eternity then your question will remain
>   there without an accepted answer till eternity too.

Also, according to the [SO guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) on accepting an answer:

> Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final
>   statement indicating that the question has now been answered
>   perfectly. It simply means that ***the author received an answer that
>   worked for him or her personally***, but not every user comes back to
>   accept an answer, and of those who do, ***they may not change the
>   accepted answer if a newer, better answer comes along later***.

Thus, it is clear that accepting an answer is a **personal and timely** decision.

---

Now, whether **at some point later you get a fitter answer or not** and what you do with it is of ***separate*** issue.

What do we do if we get/find better answer later on?

I have just recently encountered [this problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317057/i-have-accepted-an-answer-but-i-found-someones-post-has-fitter-answers-should) and I think the answer given by [Cody Gray](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray) there is quite useful to help us making decisions.

In [my case](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317057/i-have-accepted-an-answer-but-i-found-someones-post-has-fitter-answers-should), I ended up accepting the answer and choose not to change it - although better answer is present since the answer happens to work for me *and I implemented it personally at some point* - although a day later what happen was:

1. I realized that there was [a better answer elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28418522/how-do-i-map-a-column-to-uppercase-in-net-4-5-c-sharp-entity-framework-6-using/28436308#28436308), and
2. There was [someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5202563/ivan-stoev) who gave me [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35423692/ef-6-with-odp-net-oracle-manageddataaccess-how-to-use-non-capital-letter-for-cl/35457202#35457202) the way I wanted 
   (after I have accepted an answer).
3. I changed the way I implemented the solution in my project into even a different - improved way of all the answers which are not so proper to be put in SO anyway.

This is because:

1. Logically, there is still possibility that the *best* solution may even change in the future as it often happens. Be it a day or couple of years later does not make any difference - the best answer *changes* and not always be *posted*. Accepting a *working solution* early because of our lack of knowledge at the present + inability to tell the future isn't sinful at all.
2. The solution given has been working *at some point and you think that it is good enough* **before** a couple of months or years later a *better* solution comes and the new answer is of **separate issue**:

   - If the solution is truly better, the community will come and vote it up
   - At that point, you may (if you have enough reputation) unaccept the current answer and accept the better answer.
   - Or, if you don't feel good to unaccept the answr for one reason or another, you could simply upvote the better answer or giving bounty to show you gratitude.
   - Or, you could even make your own better answer and post it (in case you really make better answer).

---

In all these, the bottom line is,

> Accepting an answer and what you do when you receive better answer are
>   two different issues.

IMHO, as long as the answer is sufficiently good and is working for you at some point: **don't wait, just accept it**. Don't wait for the **best**.

> (Last note: about waiting, it may be a little different if the
>   question is on Meta discussion, however, since the answer cannot be
>   easily judged as "working or not working". Normally, on Meta question
>   - especially on discussion topic, though I think an answer is good enough, I will wait for a couple of days before accepting an answer, waiting for wider responses for community
>   - since it is a
>   *discussion* anyway.)

Comment: But there's a certain awkwardness with changing the accepted answer, so I would at least wait until it's unlikely to gather another possibly better or at least more elaborate answer anytime soon.

Comment: @Deduplicator ah yes, I don't say we should accept the answer when we think it is *not* sufficiently good. Not *sufficiently* good can mean that it is not as elaborated as we want, or we are not too happy with it though it is working and many more other reasons. I do not say that we should accept *any* working solution. No. I am just saying that if among the working solutions, there is one that we are happy with. Accept it. But if we feel that none is good enough, we can wait with the expectation that a better solution may be posted. This is okay too. All I am saying is don't wait for the best

Comment: Well, the first answer might already be good enough for me. Or at least look like it, because I just don't know what I don't know. Doesn't mean that the fourth answer, coming a short time later, won't be much better and demonstrate that the first one is fatally flawed or at least incomplete. Thus, I would always wait until most somewhat timely contributions are in. The SO-imposed 15 minutes might be long over by then.

Comment: @Deduplicator yes, please don't get me wrong. It is not that I don't agree on waiting more than 15 minutes either (the line about 15 mins is meant to be *minimum* time). But then if the answer is not working, and shown to be fatally flawed or incomplete, then changing the accepted answer later is completely legitimate and of different issue with accepting good and working answer.